# subprocess.call() gives "The system cannot find the path specified." while the file exists and can run that truly

Tags: python, anaconda, subprocess, environment

why running

```
import subprocess


# I'm going to run another python script in anaconda script like this:
#subprocess.call("C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat && python C:\test.py")
# but for simplifying the sample for here I've deleted the second part
# (in the case you didn't install python in the default path, you can replace v_activate_address with the correct address on your computer to see the result)

v_activate_address = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"
subprocess.call(v_activate_address)
```

gives. (it's not an error):

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

This code can run my test.py in anaconda environment truly but that line appears which is not desirable.
How should I get rid of that?

[the address is correct please don't say that]

answer to @Dunes comment:
[image]

Comment: Seems like an error in your `.bat` script. If the script didn't exist in the first place you'd get an exception instead. That line seems to be output from the bat script.

Comment: activate.bat file is an official file of Anaconda product and it exists. even that bat file has been run truly!

Comment: If the subrocess ran correctly it's obviously a problem with that .bat file. Maybe your Anaconda installation got messed up somehow. Anyway this seems to be out of scope regarding Python.

Comment: when we run activate.bat directly it doesn't show anything. So I guess it's related to subprocess package or maybe "call" function. maybe it needs an argument. Furthermore, I test it on another machine and faced with a similar message

Comment: You should call `cmd.exe /c activate.bat` shouldn’t you?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. substituting another batch file that e.g. echos output to a file, so you know it has run?

Comment: @barny, it gives the same result

Comment: If you just want to run a script in a virtualenv (what this subfolder of Anaconda is) then just try: `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\python.exe C:\test.py` (as the argument to `subprocess.call`).

Comment: @Dunes, then you need to install some packages. like NumPy or Pandas. but after activate base, you don't need (base is the default value)

Comment: No, you do not. That python will run with access to all packages that Anaconda has installed. `activate.bat` just makes it so that `python` calls the python in the `Scripts` folder before any other.

Comment: I've tested it first and then answered. please test it, if it's different for you maybe I have a problem with my python

Comment: Note that activating a virtualenv inside of a subprocess (which doesn't have any other commands specified to follow) does basically nothing that's useful. It doesn't activate the virtualenv for the Python interpreter that called it, nor for the shell that started that Python interpreter, nor for any *future* subprocesses separately started from the same interpreter.

Comment: If you run `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\python.exe -m site`, it will show you all the places that version of python will try importing modules from. You should see a quite a few directories listed under the `Anaconda3` directory. Compare this with `python.exe -m site`.

Comment: @Dunes, please see the new picture

Comment: @parvij, does the output occur when you remove the trailing `&& python.exe ...`?  I suspect you would need to pass `shell=True` in that case.

Comment: I would suggest running [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Filter by the offending process, and count result codes. You should find something related to an access denied or file not found, the full path missing will be there.

Comment: Ah, so the conda virtualenv is not a standard one. Using `subprocess.run(r'c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate && python c:\test.py`, shell=True)` is your best bet (NB. this uses subprocess.run instead of subprocess.call)

Comment: ok @Dunes but the message is there yet