# How can I run a python script in anaconda environment with another python script? (not by .bat ro .sh file)

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

I have a python script which I want to run it in an anaconda environment because it uses some library like NumPy and I'm not going to install them.

I can easily write something like this:

```
# for Windows:
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat && python script.py arg

# for Linux:
source activate base
python script.py arg
```

but then I should have two scripts. a batch file and a shell script which is not desirable.
I like to have a single solution and independent of OS.

So I thought maybe it's good to have a python script which activates anaconda environment then run my script.(So I can handle OS there). I could do it by subprocess.call(). However, it gives an additional message which it's not desirable and I couldn't solve it even with a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642839/subprocess-call-gives-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-while-the-f).

Now I'm asking do you have a solution to run a python script in anaconda environment with another python script? (which of course doesn't give a notification like my solution.)

Comment: `source activate base` You shouldn't do that, use a separate environment. I'm not sure I understand the whole two scripts problem. You have two Python scripts, one of which executes the other (how?) ?

Comment: I have a script which an ETL tool is going to run it. The platform can be Linux or Windows. Also, the script needs to run on ```activate base``` environment. what is your solution?

Comment: _I like to have a single solution and independent of OS._ You're going to need to create the environment anyway, right? The packages will likely be different, too.